# adding and updating velocity and acceleration in bufergeometry three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

```
let pointsM = [];

  let img = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'image' );
  let pointMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  map: img,transparent:true
  });
  let bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pointsM.push( new THREE.Vector3(Math.random() * 20 - 10, Math.random() * 20 - 10, Math.random() * 20 - 10));
  }
  bufferGeometry.setFromPoints(pointsM);
  bufferGeometry.computeVertexNormals();

  pointsmesh = new THREE.Points(bufferGeometry, pointMaterial);
  scene.add(pointsmesh)
```

The above section works fine ,
**converted from Geometry to BufferGeometry**

What id like to do is **add velocity and acceleration to the points created in the above section**, and **update them in the render loop**

i would like to **change the code below to work with buffer geometry currently it works with Geometry**

```
  render(){

  Geo.vertices.forEach(p => {
   p.vel += p.accel; 
   p.z -= p.vel;

  });
  Geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with the below code. It assumes that the velocity and acceleration for each vertex is saved in two separate arrays.

```js
// creation

const bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
const vertices = [];
const velocities = [];
const accelerations = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {

    vertices.push( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ); // x
    vertices.push( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ); // y
    vertices.push( Math.random() * 20 - 10 ); // z

    velocities.push( 0 );
    accelerations.push( Math.random() );

}

bufferGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( vertices, 3 ) );

// update

const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute( 'position' );

for ( let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i ++ ) {

    const z = positionAttribute.getZ( i );  

    const vel = velocities[ i ];
    const accel = accelerations[ i ];
    vel *= accel;
    velocities[ i ] = vel;
    z -= vel;

    positionAttribute.setZ( i, z );

}

positionAttribute.needsUpdate = true;

render();
```

BTW: `computeVertexNormals()` is not necessary in your use case. Points and lines to not need vertex normals.

Comment: Brilliant thanks , this makes it much more easier  thanks for that Michael

Comment: Thanks! Please accept the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: it works , but part of my question was how to i create these attributes velocity and acceleration to the points in the bufferGeometry , the code that you answered was to access these values and update them which i brilliant , so first part of the question how do i create these attributes in the points loop in the above code using bufferGeometry

Comment: If velocity and acceleration data are not used for rendering (meaning in the shader), it does not make sense put them into buffer attributes.

Comment: " It assumes that the velocity and acceleration for each vertex is saved in two separate arrays. " ,   i do not know how to add them in 2 separate arrays with the bufferGeometry , could you show me how to add these in the bufferGeometry in the above code

Comment: i added this ,  bufferGeometry.setAttribute('velocity', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(velocity, 3));
 bufferGeometry.setAttribute('acceleration', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(acceleration, 3));   but does not work , should i add this inside the vertex creation loop ?

Comment: This is exactly what i was after , this is brilliant cheers for this  Michael

Comment: answer accepted and worked well thank you very much for the effort

Comment: Sorry, but you did not mark it as the answer. You just upvoted it.